# Check if the entire substring is contained in a string

Tags: command-line

Taking for example two var: $a="bar/var1" and $b="var" I want to check if the content of $b is in $a, but not just each character of $b, its exact content.

I tried:

- `if [[ $a =~ .*$b*. ]]`
- `if [[ "$a" =~ .*"$b"*. ]]`
- `if [[ "$a" = *"$b"* ]`]
- `if [[ "$a" = *$b* ]]`
- `if [[ "$a" == *$b* ]]`

but the problem is always the same
if $b is "rav" or "var" the result is the same,
but I want true only if it's "var".

Comment: This ```if [[ $a =~ .*$b*. ]]; then echo here; else echo no; fi``` works ... and this ```if [[ $a =~ .*$b.* ]]; then echo here; else echo no; fi``` also!

Comment: Use `=~` when you have to test a string against a *regular expression*, not a literal string. [From the manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html): *"An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
              precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the
              right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular
              expression and matched accordingly"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

a="bar/var1"
b="var"

if [[ "$a" == *"$b"* ]]; then
  echo "Got it"
fi

b="rav"

if [[ "$a" == *"$b"* ]]; then
  echo "Got it"
fi
```

You have this in your list of attempts:

```
if [[ "$a" = *"$b"* ]]
```

You were on the right track, but you need two = symbols, not one.

Comment: thx for the help, but i've found out why it dosen't work, since in my script $a contains the result of that line: sudo fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | awk '$2 ~ /\*/ {print $1}'.   and i thought that line gave me back only the primary disk, but found out that it dosen't work as i thought, and that's why my comparison wouldn't give me the correct response c: anyway thx again!

Comment: since we are talking about comparison, can i ask why that code dosen't work?(or should i make another post?)                                                                                                                      prim=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT -nr /dev/$hdd);                                                                   if [[ "$prim" == "/" ]] echo $prim ;                                                                                           the result of the first line is / but the if wont work :'C

Comment: @userone it's `if [[ something ]];then something; fi`, or in the form `[[ something ]] && something`.

Comment: yea even like that it dosen't work

Comment: @userone Maybe you should make another post, explaining what do you want to accomplish, what is the expected result and what have you tried.

Comment: oks thx_____________